# Is it possible to get element in parent class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function A() {
    this.a = 'this is a';
    var b = 'this is b';
}

function B() {
    var self = this;
    this.c = 'this is c';
    var d = 'this is d';

    // a: undefined, b: undefined, c: this is c, d: this is d
    $("#txt1").text('a: ' + A.a + ', b: ' + b + ', c: ' + this.c + ', d: ' + d);

    C();

    function C() {
        // this.c is not defined here
        // a: undefined, b: undefined, c: this is c, d: this is d
        $("#txt2").text('a: ' + A.a + ', b: ' + b + ', c: ' + self.c + ', d: ' + d);
    }
}
B.prototype = new A();

var b = new B();
​
```

Is it possible for class B and inner function C to get variable `a` and `b`?

Fiddle file is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vTUqc/5/

Comment: No... `a` and `b` are local to those functions.

Comment: @FelixKling That's only half true. `a` is accessible in any instance of `A`, and the prototype of `B` happens to be an instance of `A`.

Comment: @Asad: Ah, I scanned the code too quickly, I just meant `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `a` in `B`, using `this.a`, since the prototype of `B` is an instance of `A`. You can also get `a` in `C`, using `self.a`:

```
function A() {
    this.a = 'this is a'; // This is accessible to any instance of A
    var b = 'this is b';  // This is not accessible outside the scope of the function
}
function B() {
    var self = this;

    alert(this.a); // Alerts 'this is a'

    C(); // Also alerts 'this is a'

    function C() {
        alert(self.a);
    }
}
B.prototype = new A();
new B();
```

You can't get `b` directly on the other hand. If you want to access it, you could use a function that returns its value:

```
function A() {
    this.a = 'this is a';
    var b = 'this is b';
    this.returnb = function(){
        return b;
    }
}
```

Now `b` is accessible to instances of `A` via `(new A()).returnb()`

Comment: So `b` is inaccessible in any case? Like private elements in parent class can't be accessed in child class in C++?

Comment: @Ovilia Yes, somewhat analogously to that. You can however make a method that can access the variable for you.

Comment: @Ovilia I have added this to the answer

Comment: @Ovilia: It's very simple and has nothing to do with inheritance. Inside functions, variables declared with `var` are local to that function and cannot be accessed from the outside. They get out of scope when the function terminates (unless you do fancy things like using closures). Just like local variables in C++ class methods I presume.